# Relation between the on-shell superspace and lightcone superspace

Tags: supersymmetry, yang-mills, superspace-formalism

There is an **on-shell** superspace (introduced by V.Nair) for $\mathcal{N} = 4$.

It is introduced in the section 4.3 in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.1697 , for instance.

Four Grassmann
variables $\eta^{I}$ are introduced (one for a given supersymmetry) and all 16 physical states of
$\mathcal{N} = 4$ super Yang-Mills  are unified into a single superfield:
$$
\Omega = g^{+} + \eta_A \lambda^{A} -\frac{1}{2!} \eta_A \eta_B S^{A B}
 - \frac{1}{3!}\eta_A \eta_B \eta_C \lambda^{A B C} + \eta_1 \eta_2 \eta_3 \eta_4 g^{-}
$$
In this formalism, supercharges are:
$$
q^{Aa} = [p|^{a} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_A} \qquad
q^{\dagger Aa} = |p \rangle^{\dot{a}} \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta_A}
$$

There also exist a similar in terms of the results approach of introducing the **lightcone superspace**. There one chooses the axial gauge, for instance $A^{+} = 0$, and then some fields, like $A^{-}$ and certain components of the spinor field can be integrated out. In this approach one is left only with propagating degrees of freedom, but at the cost of sacrificing the manifest Lorentz covariance.

Here, I'll use a notation from this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0409120v2.

In the `Mandelstam` formalism there one Grassmann coordinate $\theta^{A}$ for each supersymmetry. For the $\mathcal{N} = 4$ case, the chiral superfield is given by the following expression:
$$
\Phi(x, \theta) = \partial_+^{-1} A + \theta_A \partial_+^{-1} \bar{\lambda}^{A} + \frac{i}{2!} \eta_A \eta_B S^{A B}
 + \frac{1}{3!}\varepsilon^{A B C D} \theta_A \theta_B \theta_C \lambda_{D} + \theta_1 \theta_2 \theta_3 \theta_4 \partial_+ \bar{A}
$$

Both approaches resemble each other, because one is left only with physical degrees of freedom, and the expansion in terms of the Grassmann variables corresponds to the helicities of the particles.

However, the lightcone formulation is obtained by performing some manipulations with the initial Lagrangian, and this on-shell superspace is introduced by hand, and doesn't include these powers of derivative  $\partial_{+}$, where $x_+ = x_0 + x_3$ in the standard Lorentz coordinates.

How one can relate these both formalisms?